# instagram dataset sync

Tags: carto, instagram

I just uploaded a new photo but it has yet to show up.  I applied the query again in cartodb but still does not show.

Shouldn't it be syncing automatically?  And how long should it take using a free account?

Answer (score 2):

The Instagram connector allows to retrieve your Instagram information but it has no option yet to synchronise in real time (it's not that your plan doesn't allow it, but that the functionality does not exist at this moment).

The free plan doesn't include the Sync Tables feature, so for any other connector (such as Dropbox or Google Drive) that allows synchronization, the option wouldn't be available neither.